# NSMutableString is always "out of scope"?

Tags: iphone, nsmutablestring

in my .h file i have:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface untitled : UIViewController 
{
    NSMutableString * sResults;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableString * sResults;

@end
```

In my .m i have:

```
#import "untitled.h"


@implementation untitled

@synthesize sResults;

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    sResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];
    [sResults appendString:@" World"];
}

@end
```

Whenever i check sResults it says "Out of scope".. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.sResults = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Hello"]; //retained in synthesized setter
    [self.sResults appendString:@" World"];
}
```

Comment: This works, except i also had to do [self.sResults appendString:@" World"]; . weird why do i have to do self.sResults? Thanks

Comment: YOu need to use the self-notation, because it uses the property/synthesize you have so well written. You are accessing the array directly, if you don't use the self.